# Make Sencha Touch list (or ExtJS Grid) not observe store and auto-update UI?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

When I update a store associated with a Sencha Touch list (Ext.dataview.List), the list UI automatically updates (as in MVVM).

I'm creating a mobile app which has a ton of data coming in via a websocket, and the store is updating frequently. I believe entire list items are being re-rendered (using itemTpl) when even just one field changes. As you may imagine, this is incredibly slow, and my app is seriously lagging.

I'd like to disable this "observation" of the store by the list and update the list items myself, using innerHTML. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a way to update the store without updating the UI?

My other option is to throttle data, but that is a last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make use of the suspendEvents and resumeEvents methods. These are provided via the Observable mixin, and can be used on both stores and lists. Use suspendEvents to stop any events (like refreshing a list) and resumeEvents to start listening again. When resuming events any that were fired during suspension will queue up and fire again, so if you want to discard these events then you need to make sure to do suspendEvents(false).

Manually updating via innerHTML is going to be a huge pain, I would recommend just doing suspendEvents while you are loading the store, and whenever you want to update the list just resumeEvents and manually refresh it from the store.

See [this link](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-suspendEvents) for further reading.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing...I'm using suspendEvents(true) and resumeEvents(). However, the list will need to update so frequently (multiple times per second) that refreshing it from the store is not feasible, so I'll have to update the DOM manually.

Comment: I think suspendEvents(true) will queue up the suspend events and still fire them at resumeEvents. You probably don't want this since you will end up with a ton of repeat refreshes on the list for no reason.

Comment: Also, be careful with performance if you are updating DOM manually on a big list multiple times per second.... Have you explored utilizes template member functions maybe?